# Google Photo API - search library

Tags: search, google-photos, google-photos-api

The media:search endpoint is okay, but I really need a keyword search.  Just like the actual website has.  i.e. football

I've tried using the Google Custom Search API and pointing it to photos.google.com, but that is unable to get past the login screen even though I'm authenticated.

Anyone else have any workarounds for a keyword search?

Answer (score 2):

Keyword search is currently not supported in the Google Photos Library API.

There's a feature request on the issue tracker that you can star to draw attention to it and be notified of updates: https://issuetracker.google.com/110300471

At the moment you can search the library by what's in the photo ("content categories"), dates, media types and archived state. More information about what's currently supported is in the developer documentation: https://developers.google.com/photos/library/guides/apply-filters